# Is it possible to select lambda.1se via caret?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, glmnet, elastic-net

I'm fitting an elastic net regression model.  I've attempted this via both the glmnet and caret packages.  I'm tuning for both alpha and lambda, so I'm leaning toward caret, as it offers a cleaner way to do this.  The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to tell caret to choose lambda.1se over lambda.min when tuning for lambda.  Is this possible or do I have to stick with glmnet if I want to use lambda.1se?